# Finally back on Puzzling... and I have a new kind of puzzle (I think)

Tags: wordplay, rhyme, poetry

Oh my God. Okay, I have a lot of things to catch up on. First, a belated **HAPPY NEW YEAR!!!** to everyone. Second, have any rules on Puzzling.SE vitally changed during the past three months? And last but not least, here is the puzzle!

> I know a friend called Simeon Galavar. He loves anagrams. His motto is, "I love anagrams!" However, for someone who loves anagrams and words so much, he seems to see words and letters that are not even there! He decided to make an anagram of a poem, I forgot it. I read it and it was good, it rhymed, it was written in the same style as was the poem he anagrammed... but he asked me if I could find things in the poem that did not even exist! He asked me to find:
>
> - An X (I *deny* it exists)
> - The word "waste" (did he even write this *down*?)
> - Three small references of his name (I must have *missed* this. Must I check *back* again)?

```
Where doom is death oh I can be
All abandoned, no remains,
Solo everyday for me.
The sea dried up, I can't sit up;
Earth destroyed its own faint plains.
```

> ***Where are they?***

Apologies for not being on Puzzling.SE. I have been a little busy with anagrams myself... but must I emphasise that anagrams are not related to the actual puzzle itself. That is just for the backstory.

May someone also edit this and include other tags that are relevant if there are? Thanks, and enjoy! :D

---

**Edit:**

Partial answers are allowed, and I also removed the image file and replaced it with the font. The font is important. There were two references of Simeon's name as well, but as a sheer coincidence, there is another better one ;)

Comment: The poem is in an image file? Is that needed for the puzzle?

Comment: @rhsquared No, but the font is. I've been looking into that, and I think I can write the font *without* the image. I will do that ;)

Comment: I see what you mean. Not quite sure how to handle fonts ithough. This one looks like a console type font.

Comment: @rhsquared I think I did it, but I can't seem to put it into the yellow sandbox. Eh well, I am sure someone would figure it out ;)

Comment: @user477343 welcome back :D

Comment: @user477343 does Rot13(gur fglyr/glcr bs cbrz pbzr va gb cynl ng nyy sbe gur guveq anzr ersrerapr?)

Comment: @Brandon_J no, but (ROT13) gjb pbafrphgvir jbeqf qb. Gur guveq ersrerapr fubjf gur shyy svefg anzr, jurernf gur bguref qba'g, urapr jul vg vf gur "orggre" ersrerapr ;)

Comment: @Quintec hahah, hello! And thanks, sorry I wasn't around. I'm back now :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The X

> Is a pattern made by the d's in **d**oom, **d**eath, aban**d**one**d**, every**d**ay, **d**rie**d** and **d**estroye**d** 
>  
>  [image: X]

Waste

> Is down the left hand side with first letter of each sentence

I think the references are

Based on the clue Missing:

> Missing a syllable(?): Wher**e** doo**m** **is** death oh I can be

And Back:

> Reading backwards: ... **no** r**em**ains ... up, **I** cant't ... d it**s** own faint

Not sure about the second again...

Comment: Again with the unintended reference? Hahah, the other answer also said that was a reference. That is just a coincidence, but I guess I might edit the post then and include that as a third one. However, apart from that, everything else is correct! Well done! I cannot upvote as I have reached my daily voting limit but keep looking for the rest of the references, and welcome to the **Puzzling Stack Exchange (PSE)**! For a first answer, yours is superb, and you are definitely on the right track to solving your first puzzle here in this community! I will provide a hint: I *mis*sed the references ;)

Comment: I can make you a picture to use so others can visualise the X. Good job for making that discovery. Would you like me to edit your post and include a picture? Also, since you are new, I suggest you visit the [**Help Center**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help), particularly [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for the sake of asking questions, as you have not done that (yet). Otherwise, enjoy, and hope you share your wonderful puzzling talent on this site in the future! :D

Comment: Haha thank you, yeah the reference felt fairly forced kind of thought it wouldnt be right. Feel free to make the edit ive glanced over post formatting so it probably would take me ages to figure out how to make it look right. I will check it out thank you and try figure out these references!

Comment: By the way, there is still two more references you need to get. The sentence, "I *mis*sed the references", was simply a hint, hahah. These other references are easier than what you found, especially looking a little closer at the hint like you might do in the poem to find the references, hehe. Thereafter, I will give you the tick ;)

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, i have updated my answer to my next guess, whether its right or not who knows!

Comment: Hmm... you seem to be looking for Simeon's full name... you have the right idea about reading backwards, but think about the letters that are common to both *Simeon* and *missed*, individually. You might just find the clues then (in fact, you already have, but you misinterpreted it as a different potential clue) ;)

Comment: Eh, stuff the clues. Congratulations! :D

Answer (score 6):

**Partial answer**

Well,

> the word WASTE is written *down* at the start of the lines of the poem. And there are the following things that could be considered "small references of his name" *back* inside the poem:
> Where doo**m is** death oh I can be
> All abandoned, **no** r**em**a**i**n**s**,
> Solo everyday for **m**e.
> The sea dried up, **I** can't sit up;
> Earth destroyed it**s** own faint plains.
>  (I don't see anything that looks like "Galavar" or an abbreviation of it, though. Indeed, there is no "G" anywhere in the text.)

I haven't found

> anything to match the "denied" X.

Incidentally,

> SIMEON GALAVAR = (I LOVE ANAGRAMS)*.

Comment: Hahah, great job! I did not know there were *three* references of the name... the second one you mentioned was just a strange coincidence. But everything else you got correct, and as for the X part, I will give you a hint: *de*ny. $(+1)$ DVL13 :D

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Note that the "de" in deny as in the OP's comment is in italics, which is pronounced like a letter D alone. Therefore, I believe that *rdens1601* has the correct answer regarding the cross, which is a cross formed by the letter d's. Hope this help ;)

Comment: Yes, I agree that that bit is definitely right.